# Wpf navigation from one page to another and data grid loading large data

Tags: wpf, datagridview, navigation, desktop-application

This is the desktop application I am creating in WPF. I am using Hamburger menu library.

[Desktop application Wpf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khAwN.jpg)

I am struggling with this for last one week. I want to replace the **container** with my view model when i select item from navigation list and that view model contains large number of rows in a data grid. What is the most efficient way to navigate view models and load large number of rows in a data grid.

Here is my code

```
<Window x:Class="GymateDeskUi.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GymateDeskUi"
    xmlns:controls="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    xmlns:HamburgerMenu="clr-namespace:HamburgerMenu;assembly=HamburgerMenu"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="525" x:Name="this_">

<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Orientation="Horizontal" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="24" x:Name="progress" Visibility="{Binding visibility}"/>


    <DockPanel >
        <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu Background="#F3F3F3" 
                                     MenuIconColor="Black"
                                     SelectionIndicatorColor="#3176BC" 
                                     MenuItemForeground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:Name="enquiry" Icon="Assets/x_board-papper.png" Text="Enquiry"  SelectionCommand="{Binding ElementName=this_}" CommandParam="enquiry" />
            <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:Name="member" Icon="Assets/x_user.png" Text="Member"  SelectionCommand="{Binding ElementName=this_}" CommandParam="member"/>
            <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:Name="invoice" Icon="Assets/x_paper.png" Text="Invoice" SelectionCommand="{Binding ElementName=this_}" CommandParam="invoice"  />
            <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:Name="reciept" Icon="Assets/x_file-success.png" Text="Reciept" SelectionCommand="{Binding ElementName=this_}" CommandParam="reciept"/>

        </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu>

        <controls:ModernFrame x:Name="Container"></controls:ModernFrame>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

This is HamburgerMenu.

```
    static HamburgerMenuItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenuItem)));
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get {             
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));


    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Brush SelectionIndicatorColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectionIndicatorColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionIndicatorColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionIndicatorColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionIndicatorColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Blue));

    public ICommand SelectionCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectionCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string CommandParam
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CommandParamProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParamProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParamProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParam", typeof(string), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer. What do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry,  I am new to this..I just simply want navigation mechanism with data grid.